# react-loadable multiple resource loading not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, code-splitting, react-loadable

To increase the site performance I was thinking of code splitting some of my components which I don't need at the initial build. After looking for some options I decided to go with [react-loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable).

According to react-loadable docs, we can load [multiple resources](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable#loading-multiple-resources) in parallel. With this idea and the example code given into the docs I was [trying to implement](https://codesandbox.io/s/w59mwn625) a component which fetch the component as well as the data needed to render the component. But the problem that I'm facing is that every time I tried to use `Loadable.Map` function I'm getting an `TypeError: loader is not a function` in the console and only loading state is being shown. Did the docs is broken or My implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items in the `loader` object need to be functions

so change

```
Loadable.Map({
  loader: {
    Post: () => import("./Post"),
    data: fakeAPI()
  },
```

to

```
Loadable.Map({
  loader: {
    Post: () => import("./Post"),
    data: () => fakeAPI()
  },
```

or even

```
Loadable.Map({
  loader: {
    Post: () => import("./Post"),
    data: fakeAPI
  },
```

see updated demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/my19zqk78